# Pandas python updating values in a table based on preexisting values and conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({
'Player': ['John','John','John','Steve','Steve','Ted', 'James','Smitty','SmittyJr','DJ'],
'Name': ['A','B', 'A','B','B','C', 'A','D','D','D'],
'Group':['2A','1B','2A','2A','1B','1C','2A','1C','1C','2A'],
'Medal':['G', '?', '?', 'S', 'B','?','?','?','G','?']
})

df =  df[['Player','Group', 'Name', 'Medal']]
print(df)
```

I want to update all the '?' in the column `Medal` with values for any of the rows with matching `Name` & `Group` columns that are already filled in.

For example since the first `row 0` is `Name:A, Group:2A, Medal:G`, then the '?' on `row 6` and `2` would be 'G'

The results should look like:

```
res=pd.DataFrame({
'Player': ['John','John','John','Steve','Steve','Ted', 'James','Smitty','SmittyJr','DJ'],
'Name': ['A','B', 'A','B','B','C', 'A','D','D','D'],
'Group':['2A','1B','2A','2A','1B','1C','2A','1C','1C','2A'],
'Medal':['G', 'B', 'G', 'S', 'B','?','G','G','G','?']
})

res =  res[['Player','Group', 'Name', 'Medal']]
print(res)
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) `?` by last value (with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html)) of sorted `Medal` (with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html)) in each group:

```
df['Medal'] = df.groupby(['Group','Name'])['Medal']
                .apply(lambda x: x.replace('?', x.sort_values().iloc[-1]))

print(df)
     Player Group Name Medal
0      John    2A    A     G
1      John    1B    B     B
2      John    2A    A     G
3     Steve    2A    B     S
4     Steve    1B    B     B
5       Ted    1C    C     ?
6     James    2A    A     G
7    Smitty    1C    D     G
8  SmittyJr    1C    D     G
9        DJ    2A    D     ?
```

**Timings**:

```
In [81]: %timeit (df.groupby(['Group','Name'])['Medal'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('?', x.sort_values().iloc[-1])))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.13 ms per loop

In [82]: %timeit (df.replace('?', np.nan).groupby(['Name', 'Group']).apply(lambda df: df.ffill().bfill()).fillna('?'))
100 loops, best of 3: 11.3 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

myfill = lambda df: df.ffill().bfill()
df.replace('?', np.nan).groupby(['Name', 'Group']).apply(myfill).fillna('?')

     Player Group Name Medal
0      John    2A    A     G
1      John    1B    B     B
2      John    2A    A     G
3     Steve    2A    B     S
4     Steve    1B    B     B
5       Ted    1C    C     ?
6     James    2A    A     G
7    Smitty    1C    D     G
8  SmittyJr    1C    D     G
9        DJ    2A    D     ?
```